# A promise was created in a route but not returned from

Tags: node.js, express, promise, bluebird, knex.js

i tried to find a solution for this warning i get, but none of the suggested approaches worked for me. I don't want to disable this warning, because i believe this warning is there for a reason, but i can't figure out whats the real deal here.

I have the following route defined on my node.js server running express:

```
// GET all items
router.get('', helpers.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
  debug("Get all items");
  return knex.select('*').from('routes')
    .then((routes) => {
      res.send(routes);
      return null;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      debug("error getting routes");
      res.send({ error: "Fehler beim Laden" });
      return null;
    });
});
```

My Middleware loginRequired does not use any promise at all

```
function loginRequired(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        req.flash('loginMessage', 'Du musst eingeloggt sein!');
        req.session.redirectTo = req.path;
        return res.redirect('/');
    } else {
        return next();
    }
}
```

I use knex for accessing my database, which creates promises.

And everytime i hit the route, i get the following warning:

```
(node:10568) Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned fr
om it, see *link*
    at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (C:\Users\qxr1088\Desktop\Privat\GPS
\bibis-tracker\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\method.js:29:9)
```

As you can see i tried to add the "return null;" statements as suggested by bluebird, but this does not fix the problem.

Comment: It's likely happening in some middleware where you call `next` from a promise callback

Comment: Added my loginRequired Middleware code, there is no promise at all.

Comment: Is that your complete code?

Comment: Yes, thats the complete code for the GET route '' with middleware loginRequired

Comment: This is just a guess, but remove all of your `return` statements, they're not needed.

Comment: Same here :/. Odly removing the catch statement make the warning disappear, but it's obviously not an option. If you have a solution I would love to heart it.